# Java Card Applet converter exception

Tags: javacard

I have an issue with Java Card applet converter. When trying to convert my CLASS files to CAP format, the converter throws an exception for one of them, and I am clueless as how to resolve this issue. Here's the message I am receiving:

```
Java Card 2.2.1 Class File Converter, Version 1.3
Copyright 2003 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved. Use is subject to license terms.

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Verification failed

conversion completed with 1 errors and 0 warnings.
```

And here's my OPT file:

```
-out EXP JCA CAP
-exportpath C:\java_card_kit-2_2_1\api_export_files;P:\abc\def\Applets\dist\
-d ..\dist
epurse
0xAB:0xA6:0xA0:0xA5:0xA0:0xA5:0xA2:0xA3:0xA5 1.0
```

I am developing 5 applets simultaneously and this is the only one which has been giving me a headache. Has anyone ever had this kind of problem with Java Card converter?

Comment: What JDK did you use to build your `.class` file? See this issue: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1754856?start=0

Comment: @vojta 1.4.2 Update 15. I have been using it for all my applet developments for two years now

Comment: Can you please share this applet source?

Comment: @Abraham Unfortunately the NDA does not allow me to. What I can say is, this applet would convert until I modified another applet, to which this applet obtains a shared interface. After that, this applet (the receiver end of the shared interface) won't convert any more. In the mean time, I'll try to obtain company approval to publish applet source code

Comment: Dear iMan, have you solved the problem?

Comment: @Abraham I don't know if this counts as solving my problem... I had an abstract class which extended `Applet`, and had a protected method with `DESKey` as one of its parameters. After I removed that parameter, everything worked perfectly. I checked and checked again, and the issue seems to be passing classes as parameters to protected methods